# Firefox extension redirect from one page to another on request

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

So I have site insecure://site.com, and I want to make an extension that redirects me to insecure://site2.com every time I visit insecure://site.com;
Here is my background.js:

```
var host = "insecure://site2.com";
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) {
        return {redirectUrl: host + details.url.substr(16,details.url.length)};
    },
    {
    urls: [
        "insecure://site.com"
    ],
    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "stylesheet", "script", "image", "object", "xmlinsecurerequest", "other"]
    },
    ["blocking"]
);
```

And here is part of manifest.json:

```
"background": {"scripts":["background.js"]},
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "contextMenus",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "insecure://site.com/*",
    "secure://site.com/*",
    "insecure://site2.com/*",
    "secure://site2.com/*"
]
```

Comment: insecure:// is http:// and secure is https://

Answer (score 0):

You could check [`window.location.protocol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/protocol) and act accordingly based on that:

```js
if (window.location.protocol === 'http:') { // Insecure
  window.location.href = "https://www.example.com"; // Redirect to website
}
```